# Javascript - Catch leaving site user's leave and cancel actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

[image: Leaving the site alert box]

I have to set the flag (*isOpen = 0*) when user is leaving the site while clicking the 'Leave' button. Is there a direct way to catch the **Leave** button click event?

**Edited:**
We are developing a process flow diagram application. One diagram can access by multiple users in the same group, in that case, if one user open the diagram for edit purpose then system should not allow to edit for another user. So we have set flag isOpen =1 when open the diagram, once closed (customized close button from the page) we set isOpen=0. These scenarios are working fine except user is closing the browser window.

**Browser closing scenario:**
Please refer the top image. If user close the tab then browser will ask to confirm the action., in that case user 
1) User shall leave 
2) User shall cancel and stay the page
I cannot set isOpen=0 for window.onbeforeunload() event because if user shall cancel and stay the same page. So we need to catch the Leave/Cancel user actions to set the flag.

*Please suggest me an alternate solution if it is not possible to catch leave/cancel user actions.*

Comment: No. The page is unloaded with no further JS logic being executed. Also setting a variable as the page is closed seems rather pointless.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated the question with more details. Please check and let us know your response.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is not possible using this logic, the reason is that when a browser tab is closed, all JS execution stops (quite logically since the tab was closed).

Al alternative way to do this is to solve the problem differently. Every couple of seconds (or minutes, depending on your use case) you can send a `fetch/ajax` request as an "I'm connected" flag. When a user stops sending such a flag it means they closed the tab or it became inactive. If the user reopens it, you will start receiving that user's flag again.

This can be solved more elegantly using WebSockets, which does exactly what I outlined above out of the box. You just need to keep track of your users by their "flag", be it an ID, cookie, etc.